# Adding a css class / div wrapper to a block

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

I have the below XML which adds my static block to the page sidebar, then removes the wishlist. I would like to add a div wrapper to this static block with a css class.

I thought this could be done with the following argument, but it does not work.

```
<argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">faq</argument>
```

Here is the full XML so far if anyone could help it would be appreciated.

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
   <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="faq_sidebar">
       <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">faq_sidebar</argument>
            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">faq</argument>
       </arguments>
   </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add  class like this

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional" htmlClass="css_class" htmlTag="div">
   <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="faq_sidebar">
       <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">faq_sidebar</argument>
            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">faq</argument>
       </arguments>
   </block>
```

Check this http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-types.html

Answer (score 2):

For adding class or div wrapper to a block I would suggest to use container.
eg-

```
<container name="div.faq.block" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="faq_sidebar" after="-">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="faq_sidebar" >
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">faq_sidebar</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
</container>
```